# R getting mean for every nth row

Tags: r, matrix, apply, sapply

is there a more elegant way of getting a mean for current to prior nth row?  For example,

```
x=replicate(3, rnorm(20))
```

what I want is to get a mean of the column 2 for each row + 2 rows prior.  The way I currently would do this is to 1) create an empty column 2) loop through each row and get values from prior 2 rows, mean it, then store it in the new column. It's tedious so I'm wondering if there is cleaner, faster method?  thanks in advance. ahdee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `filter` - what you are doing is a rolling mean.

```
filter(x[,2], rep(1/3,3), sides=1)
```

Comment: thanks; the rolling mean is spot on.  I googled around and found a library zoo, which works great for me. `library(zoo) ; rollapply(x[,2], 2, mean, na.pad = 1, align="right")`

Answer (score 2):

thanks to thelatemail what I wanted is called a rolling mean.  I found a solution.

```
library(zoo)
x=replicate(3, rnorm(20))

rollapply(x[,2], 2, mean, na.pad = 1, align="right")
```

Comment: Yep, that's equivalent to `filter(x[,2], rep(1/2,2), sides=1)` from my answer. `rollapply` is a more generic version of the same sort of logic. Good to see you sorted it out.

Comment: Hi I have a 7700 x 1 dataframe. 7700 are number of days. I would like to create a 1100 x 1 dataset with 7 day averages instead so that I have my data in weeks. So the first entry should be the mean(1:7), second entry mean(8.14) and so on.